# Tableau date filter based on table values

Tags: tableau-desktop

In the database I'm working with, there is a table with date ranges, which is separate from the main data I'm pulling, but I would like to use the table for filter options.

This is the main table with the data I need:

| Data | MatchingID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 59 |
| B | 59 |
| C | 7 |

This is the table with the date ranges that I would like to have as filter options, it is inner joined with the table above but none of the data is needed except for filtering purposes:

| Start Dt | End Dt | Type | MatchingID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-12 | 2023-07-03 | Year23 | 59 |
| 2023-07-04 | 2023-07-10 | Week2 | 59 |
| 2023-06-04 | 2023-06-10 | Week2 | 7 |

Is it possible to use this table to create a date filter that the user could select the Type they want and it show only data from Start date to End date?

I tried using a calculated field for this, but, perhaps due to my limited knowledge, it does not seem possible to do this.

Comment: This sounds fairly simple, but I'm unclear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Can there be more than one row with the same type? Is this table joined with another table which has the actual data, or are you trying to filter on the table you showed in your post?

Comment: @pladams9 The type field is unique because it has Year 23, Year 22, as so on. The dates are from a joined table that is within my custom SQL query.

Comment: Can you add a more full description of the data source you are using to the question? What the tables are, how they are joined, etc.

Comment: @pladams9 I updated the original question with more details about the tables involved. Hopefully it is easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an inner join for the two tables, the resulting data in your final table should simply look like this:

| Data | MatchingID | Start Dt | End Dt | Type | MatchingID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 59 | 2022-07-12 | 2023-07-03 | Year23 | 59 |
| A | 59 | 2023-07-04 | 2023-07-10 | Week2 | 59 |
| B | 59 | 2022-07-12 | 2023-07-03 | Year23 | 59 |
| B | 59 | 2023-07-04 | 2023-07-10 | Week2 | 59 |
| C | 7 | 2023-06-04 | 2023-06-10 | Week2 | 7 |

Since you say you would like the user to be able to select the `Type`, you can simply drag the `Type` pill to the filters shelf, and then right-click it and select "Show Filter".